# How to calculate the number of simple cycles in a complete, directed graph.

Tags: graph-theory, permutation-cycles

In his article "Finding all the elementary circuits of a directed graph", Donals B. Johnson provides the following equations and states that it calculates the number of elementary circuits in a complete directed graph with n vertices.
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{n-i+1}(n-i)!
$$

And I was wondering how to rewrite the middle-parentheses and calculate this as I am not sure whether this is the notation for combinations, permutations or something else.

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to me to write it as
$$
\sum_{j=2}^{n} \binom{n}{j}(j-1)!
$$
or perhaps
$$
\sum_{j=2}^{n} \binom{n}{j} \frac{j!}{j},
$$
that is, the number of ways to pick $j$ of the $n$ vertices, and choose a cyclic order of those $j$ vertices.

I started at 2, assuming that a single vertex is not a cycle.
With an undirected graph, we'd probably say two vertices can't be a cycle, and start with $j = 3$.

But starting from $j = 2$ is equivalent to your formula, with the substitution $i = n - j + 1$.

Comment: This sure looks like a better way to write it, but my question of how to write the middle parenthesis so that a numerical value can be calculated still stands. And yes, a cycle needs to consist of at least 3 vertices, since it is directed and cannot include loops (edges (v, v)) or multiple edges between the same vertices.

Comment: Well, the formula you gave does include pairs of vertices!

Comment: $\binom{n}{k}$ is the binomial coefficient, "n choose k", the number of ways to choose k out of n things. It can be written $n!/((n-k)!k!)$ but you don't really want to calculate it that way. Better is $n^{\underline{k}}/k!$, multiplying just $k$ terms descending from $n$, but nearly any calculator or programming language should let you calculate it directly.